# can jsTree use radio check

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, plugins, jstree

i know there is a plugin for jsTree named jquery.tree.checkbox.js.
that make the tree node multi checkable.

i just wondered if there is a plugin to raido check the tree node?
or how can i modify jquery.tree.checkbox.js to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can simply be done by adding the attribute

```
    rules:{
            multiple : false
          }
```

Inside the configuration of the tree.
This will make it impossible to choose multiple entries.

Answer (score 5):

@Asaf's answer seems to no longer work on version 3.3.1 in 2016. You now need to set `multiple` on `core`:

```
$jstree.jstree({
    core: {
        multiple: false,
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting `multiple:false` will still allow cascading so you need to turn that off too.

version `3.3.3`

```
$(".tree").jstree({
    plugins: ["checkbox"],
    core: {
        data: ...,
        multiple: false
    },
    checkbox: {
        three_state: false,
        cascade: "none"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The radio button option is still not released, so you have to change the chceckbox option as single select.

```
bind('check_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    var currentNode = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
    $("#tree").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each 
        (function () { 
            if(currentNode != this.id){
                jQuery.jstree._reference($("#tree")).uncheck_node('#'+this.id);
            }
        }); 
});
```

refer this http://jsfiddle.net/bwTrP/1/

Answer (score 1):

Using jsTree version 3.2.1 with the checkbox plugin it is possible to emulate radiobutton behaviour handling the 'changed' event as follows:

```
//jstree configuration:
'checkbox': {
    three_state: false, //required for the cascade none to work
    cascade: 'none' //no auto all_children<->parent selection
},
//...

var resetting = false;
$('#tree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    if (resetting) //ignoring the changed event
    {
        resetting = false;
        return;
    }
    if ($("#multiselect").is(':checked') == false && data.selected.length > 1) {
        resetting = true; //ignore next changed event
        data.instance.uncheck_all(); //will invoke the changed event once
        data.instance.check_node(data.node/*currently selected node*/);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: [JSTree radiobutton behaviour example using checkbox plugin](https://jsfiddle.net/mrc4fun/0a9r0902/)